# When executing an sql query, an error occurs, why?

Tags: java

My database:

Table Client:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTXrL.jpg)

The genderCode field is bound to the Gender table.

Table Gender:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCPH6.jpg)

Request processing code:

```
public static ResultSet executeQuery (String sql) {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        System.out.println(sql);
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            if (sql.contains("SELECT")) {
                resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            } else {
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();

        }
        return resultSet;

    }
```

Request: INSERT INTO client (FirstName, LastName, Patronymic, Birthday, RegistrationDate, Email, Phone, GenderCode, PhotoPath) VALUES ('111', '111', '111', '1999-10-10', '2021-04-14 10:09:28', '111', '111', 'м', '111')

Error:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`demotest`.`client`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Client_Gender` FOREIGN KEY (`GenderCode`) REFERENCES `gender` (`Code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I pass the values to the request like this:

```
DBHandler.executeQuery("INSERT INTO client " +
                                "(FirstName, LastName, Patronymic, Birthday, RegistrationDate, Email, Phone, GenderCode, PhotoPath) VALUES " +
                                "('"+firstName+"', '"+lastName+"', '"+patronymic+"', '"+birthday+"', '"+simpleDateFormat.format(regDate)+"', '"+email+"', '"+phone+"', 'м', '"+photoPath+"')");
```

I can't use the PreparedStatement.setString because I don't know the amount of data being passed.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to execute the query manually in MySql Workbench or in an other MySql client?

Comment: no, in workbench it works

Comment: Ok, I think the problem could be in the way the Java program connect to the db. Please, could share it?  If in the program is used a connection string (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","root");), please share it.

Comment: "I can't use the PreparedStatement.setString because I don't know the amount of data being passed." That shouldn't stop you from using PreparedStatement. Your current approach is *highly* vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks. I would very, very strongly advise you to embrace the parameterized queries appropriately.

Comment: Furthermore you could log the query adding the following line, so you can check it: System.out.println(preparedStatement);

Comment: what does it mean to register a request?